# How do I get through Vault 15? I'm told I need a rope, but can't find one

Tags: fallout

I'm playing the original *Fallout* for the first time. I beat up some cave rats outside of Vault 13 and made it to Vault 15. However, I can't figure out how to progress in it. I made it to the elevator shaft, but I'm told that I need a rope for it. I've thoroughly searched the area, but I can't find one. How do I get past this and continue through Vault 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a generic "rope" item to use on the shaft, and there isn't one in the immediate area. The complete locations are listed on the wiki: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Rope

> Seth sells this.
>
> Two in Shady Sands; one in a bookshelf in one of the buildings near
>   the brahmin and one on the floor in the hut next to the field where
>   the plants are growing.
>
> One in Vault 15 on the second floor.
>
> Three on the table in the merchants room inside The Cathedral.
>
> One on the bookcase in Killian Darkwater's room in Junktown.
>
> Mitch sells this.

Comment: Huh, I had thought this was more of a puzzle rather than anything else, and that the solution was on the Vault 15 map. I have no idea where those places are, but I guess that’s part of the journey.

Comment: You should have passed Shady Sands at least on your way to Vault 15.

Comment: Just remember Fallout is from the era where they really don't hand hold you at all.  You can easily walk to an area that will instant kill you.  Puzzles are also solved with items from all over the world.